# Declaring arrays statically in Constants file

Tags: objective-c, static, constants

I'm declaring a number of static arrays in a Constants.m file, for example the numberOfRowsInSection count for my tableView:

```
+ (NSArray *)configSectionCount
{
    static NSArray *_configSectionCount = nil;
    @synchronized(_configSectionCount) {
        if(_configSectionCount == nil) {
            _configSectionCount = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], [NSNumber numberWithInt:4], [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];
        }
        return _configSectionCount;
    }
}
```

Is this the best way to do it and is it necessary to declare them all like this?

Comment: Look into `dispatch_once` instead of the `@synchronized`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do is:

```
// main.m
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Constants.h"
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        [Constants class];
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, 
                   NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}

// Constants.h
extern NSArray* configSectionCount;
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Constants : NSObject
@end

// Constants.m
#import "Constants.h"
@implementation Constants
NSArray* configSectionCount;
+(void)initialize {
    configSectionCount = @[@2, @2, @4, @3, @0];
}
@end
```

Now any *.m* file that imports *Constants.h* has access to `configSectionCount`. To make that even easier, my *.pch* file contains this:

```
// the .pch file
#import "Constants.h"
```

Done. Now `configSectionCount` is absolutely global. (You really should give such globals a specially formatted name, like `gCONFIG_SECTION_COUNT`. Otherwise you won't understand where it comes from tomorrow.)

Comment: great thanks - looks like a really clean way to do it

Comment: No problem. You understand the purpose of saying `[Constants class]` in the _main.m_ file, right? It is to cause the Constants class to come into existence and its `initialize` to be run, _before_ any other class (such as AppDelegate) is instantiated, and thus initialize our globals. If you dislike that approach, you could do the same thing in AppDelegate itself, if that is early enough.

Comment: yup, I think I prefer in AppDelegate as that is fine for my needs. Just refactored my app using your method and my code is so much more manageable.  I also didn't know about that shorthand `arrayWithObjects` and `numberWithInt` syntax - so updated all of those too and it's much prettier!

Comment: Xcode will update all your notation to "modern Objective-C" if you ask it to: Edit > Refactor > Convert to Modern Objective-C Syntax.